# How should I handle permission/role checking in this situation?

Tags: symfony

I have a CMS system where admin can create user groups and can grant permissions to groups to do certain things. The permissions (CRUD) are granted on the objects (i.e: can add post, can edit own post, can delete someone else's post, ...)

It's easy to come to the conclusion that we should use something like the provided ACL and store permissions on object or class. However, the question is where should we put these security checking code?

One thing came to my mind was to put that in the controller, but now it means I have to edit every controller I have, or even if I don't I need to somehow identify the object/class that the specific controller action is trying to modify. Sometimes, the controller action will involve several objects/models at once and that makes things even more complicated.

I could also put that in the manager, so that whenever I invoke the save() method I can check for permission. For some reason, that approach seems wrong in term of performance and complexity.

I have read many posts explaining voters, acl and such for Symfony and I understand all that but I'm having trouble putting all that into a solution that would avoid dirty hacks such as editing every single controller.

Comment: Why do you say that putting the auth checks in your domain manager is wrong in terms of performance? How complex is your ACL? Do you load it ahead of time for every request or do you need additional queries to check for authorization? Without seeing any code, I would say that centralizing the logic in the `save()` operation is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Couple reference links: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#security-voters and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html .  I don't consider editing 'every single controller' hacky, although there are definitely ways around that if you want - for instance, using listeners to check the Controller action (new, save, etc.).  It's tough to post an answer though without a specific question here.